# Punches on punch bag for muscle gain

Tags: cardio, muscle-gain, boxing

Will punching a punch bag fast and for a decent amount of time help in muscle gain ?

The reason I ask this is because when I punch the punch bag I feel my bicep and shoulder muscles starting to fatigue and they feel more pumped.

What are the benefits of punching a punch bag and will this be enough for decent fat loss/muscle gain.

When I mean muscle gain I don’t mean massive gains just decent gains.

Comment: No, but it will help with muscular endurance for the muscles being used, at least somwhat.

Answer (score 1):

When punching things force is maximal and velocity decreases because it is a concentric only movement.

Concentric only movements can build small amounts of muscles, but it has been proven that exercises which include an eccentric or even eccentric only exercises produce immensly more strength and muscle even at smaller volumes [source](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1835816/)

Eccentric only produced more muscle than concentric only even when the guys doing only eccentrics were performing half the volume.

This is why I also believe some exercises are only good to test strength while others actually build it, as I have hinted in another [answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/42192/33400) of mine